# Does JavaScript compile the function every time it is invoked?

Tags: javascript, compiler-optimization

Say I have this function:

```
function A() {
  function B() {
    return 1;
  }

  return 1 + B();
}
```

Does function *B* gets compiled every time when I call function *A*?

I remember someones says it won't. But my memory gets rusty, and I cannot find the reference.

Comment: JavaScript is an interpreted language... What do you mean compiled?

Comment: I don't know which optimizations different engines apply, but on the JavaScript level, each invocation of A will create a new function B.

Comment: @Josiah: Engines in modern browsers do  JIT compilation.

Comment: @FelixKling: yep, but JavaScript is still an interpreted language no matter what the backend does. Even then JIT is "just" interpretation with caching

Comment: @JosiahHester You are not correct. Modern engines contain a classic front-end and back-end and generate native code. This is referred to as JIT, or Just-in-time, compilation of the code. The code is compiled. The antiquated notion of the dichotomy of interpreted vs. compiled languages is a thing of the past.

Comment: Sorry guys for all the confusion. I meant JIT when I say compilation. I just want to know how modern JS engine optimize code execution. Thanks for all the answer :)

Comment: @chuckj I bow to your expertise. Guess I'm still stuck in the netscape age.

Comment: Profiling that code against similar code that puts "B" outside of "A" should give you a good indication of whether "B" gets compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JavaScript standard states that a JavaScript execution environment must parse the function and produce early errors refusing to execute any code in the script if they exist (such as missing close quotes, unmatched curly braces etc.). It says nothing about what happens after than.

However, all modern engines will produce native code corresponding to the function prior to executing it. All subsequent invocations will use the code generated earlier. There are times where an engine will regenerate the code by using information it collected by execution or it might inline the code of the function if it can determine that would result in better execution time.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is an interpreted language, not a compiled one, therefore it never compiles the function.

Edit: Unless your javascript engine optimized by compiling, in which case it depends on which engine it is but don't worry about it because it's not going to recompile it without a reason.

Comment: You should tell that the guys working on V8 and tell them that their JIT compilation doesn't exist!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean *invoked* (or *called*) as opposed to compiled, the answer is yes. B is invoked everytime A is invoked as A calls B.